# How can I set if else conditions inside the for loop?

Tags: c++

I try to do this, but the loop doesn't work for some reason, it just skips it.

I need to do if the `i` variable is greater than `10` then check the `g` condition and if it is equal to `1` complete the loop

until two conditions are met the loop should not end

```
int main() {

    for (int i = 0, g = 12; i < 10 ? g == 1 : false; i++, g--)
    {
        std::cout << i << " | " << g << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to do if the `i` variable is greater than `10` then check the
> `g` condition and if it is equal to `1` complete the loop...

Your usage to [Conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator)
there is wrong.

Instead, you should be simply using [logical `&&` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) there

```
for (int i = 0, g = 12; /*first condition*/ && /* second condition */ ; i++, g--)
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Therefore, you need:

```
for (int i = 0, g = 12; i < 10 && g >= 1 ; i++, g--)
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The above loop will first check whether the `i` is less than `10`, if `true` will check the next condition which is `g` is grater than or equal to `1`: if that is also `true`: do the iteration!

Comment: I read it as `g != 1`. (Complete, i.e. stop the loop when g is 1). Who's correct?

Comment: @Bathsheba I think this one is direct translation of OP's code, but not what they want, because the loop will never be entered. If `i < 10` then the result is `g == 1`

Comment: `for (int i = 0, g = 12; i < 10 && g >= 1 ; i++, g--)` does not work `g` is equal to `3` at this moment

Comment: @fox As per what you asked in the question, the above will do the job. The `g >= 1` is `true` for all the cases when `g==12, 11, 10, 9, 8,.....,3, 2, 1`.

Comment: but I need the main condition to be `i` and then check `g`.
 
if `i` is correct and `g` is not correct the loop should work

Comment: @fox Then you need to negate the second condition `for (int i = 0, g = 12; i < 10 & !(g == 1) ; i++, g--)`

Comment: Oooh it works :) `for (int i = 0, g = 5; i < 10 || g >= 1; i++, g--)`

Comment: Nicked your conditional on `g` which must be correct as the OP has accepted. Have an upvote for good feelings (and this is a good answer).

Comment: `for (int i = 0, g = 5; i < 10 || !(g == 1); i++, g--)` this option is the best for me

Answer (score 0):

Just use AND operator as `for (int i = 0, g = 12; i < 10 && g > 1; i++, g--)` and don't try to use something more complex when the simple solution works.

Why use lot word when few word do trick?